# How to modify this view using GridBagLayout

Tags: swing, jbutton, jlabel, gridbaglayout, jspinner

I would be grateful if you could help me to modify this interface. I just started learning GridBagLayout and I want to figure out how I can implement the drawn interface using GridBagLayout()

```
|-----------------------------------------------|
| Playing File: name of the file                | //This JLabel should cover the entire space
|-----------------------------------------------| 
| 00:00:00 ----#---------------------- 00:00:00 | //This has on the left and on the right side two labels and in the middle a JSpinner
|-----------------------------------------------|
|  [Open]  [Play]  [Pause]  [Rewind]  [Save]    | //This line contains 5 buttons
|-----------------------------------------------|
```

Please find in attachment a working example

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Sample extends JPanel
{

    private JLabel labelFileName = new JLabel("Playing File:");
    private JLabel labelTimeCounter = new JLabel("00:00:00");
    private JLabel labelDuration = new JLabel("00:00:00");

    private JButton buttonOpen   = new JButton("  Open  ");
    private JButton buttonPlay   = new JButton("  Play  ");
    private JButton buttonPause  = new JButton("  Pause ");
    private JButton buttonRewind = new JButton(" Rewind ");
    private JButton buttonSave   = new JButton("  Save  ");

    private JSlider sliderTime = new JSlider();

    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    public Sample() 
    {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        sliderTime.setValue(0);

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.gridwidth = 5; 
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(labelFileName, constraints);

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1; 
        add(labelTimeCounter, constraints);

        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.gridwidth = 3; 
        add(sliderTime, constraints);

        constraints.gridx = 4;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1; 
        add(labelDuration, constraints);

        JPanel panelButtons = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 25, 5));
        panelButtons.add(buttonOpen);
        panelButtons.add(buttonPlay);
        panelButtons.add(buttonPause);
        panelButtons.add(buttonRewind);
        panelButtons.add(buttonSave);

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 2;
        add(panelButtons, constraints);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                runApp();

            }
        });
    }

    public static void runApp() 
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(800, 200);
        frame.add( new Sample());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation
    }
```

}

Thanks

Comment: You'd do good with something that allows you to debug a layout. Other than that: `sliderTime` should have width 3, not 2. `panelButtons` should have width 5, not 1. Also, you probably want to set the weightx for the second column to be positive.

Comment: Don't forget `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation`. Can't stand when people forget that in an mcve. If I forget to add it, a lot of times I'll end up with a million background programs when testing :-)

Comment: @Ordous constraints.gridwidth = 5 for panelButtons solved 80% of the issue thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest a one column grid with three rows.

- The top row can be a panel set to **flowlayout**, or you could drop the label in directly. It is up to you to set the size of the label. Layout managers can't do that for you.
- The middle row would be a **borderlayout** where the spinner is set to center, and the two labels are placed at east and west.
- The bottom row should be a panel set with a **flowlayout**. To get the buttons nicely spaced out in your diagram, can only be done with a flowlayout.

My only concern would be that the slider panel could be resized in the vertical direction. In that case you might want to ditch the GridBaglayout, and just have a borderlayout on top where the top row is center, and the bottom two rows are packed into a panel that is south.

Comment: Well, this answer looks good, however, I wanted to use GridBagLayout() to do the interface. I know how to use other layouts to fix it, but the purpose of my question was to learn a bit more the GridBagLayout. Of course you are still using in part the GridBagLayout

Comment: your diagram isn't really a fit for 100% GridBagLayout usage. You could probably do it, but it would be pretty difficult. The buttons and slider don't match up to any columns, so I can't see more than a 3x1 Grid in your case.